# Crystal Report : formula for Splitting string

Tags: split, crystal-reports, report

I have string coming in this: 12345

I want to split the string above to result: 1-2-3-4-5

Pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its always 5 digits

```
picture("12345","x-x-x-x-x")
```

or for a string of any length

```
stringvar a := "111225678784";
stringvar b := "x";
numbervar c;
stringvar output;
for c := 2 to len(a) do
(
b := b +"-x"
);
output := picture(a,b);
```

replace "111225678784" with your field

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
stringvar s;
stringvar result;
numbervar i;

s:= "123456";

if len(s) < 2 
then s
else (
    result := s[1];

    for i:= 2 to len(s) do 
    (
        result := result + "-" + s[i];
    );

    result;
)
```